# How to use variable in t-sql query

Tags: t-sql

Today I get my database name like that :

```
set @databaseNameTXT = 'NewStat1DB';
```

And then I insert the data to the right table like that:

```
IF @databaseNameTXT = 'NewStat1DB' 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [NewStat1DB] (wStat_id) values(@wStat_id)
    END

IF @databaseNameTXT = 'NewStat2DB'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [NewStat2DB] (wStat_id) values(@wStat_id)
    END
```

How can I use the variable inside the t-sql and run it, something like:

INSERT INTO [@databaseNameTXT] (wStat_id) values(@wStat_id)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for this, though you need to be careful of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Database, schema, table and column names cannot be variables - the only way to do this is use dynamic SQL.

For example (this is vulnerable to SQL Injection):

```
sp_executesql 'INSERT INTO [' + @databaseNameTXT + 
                '] (wStat_id) values(' + @wStat_id + ');';
```

I suggest reading the linked article - it is a comprehensive treatment of the subject of dynamic SQL.

Comment: This is prone to SQL injection and should not be used.

Comment: If you are trying to send in a table name dynamically, there is close to a 100% chance that you have a poor design.

Comment: SQL injection attacks are not a factor in every use case.  If he's not getting data from a publicly accessible source, it doesn't really matter.  For example, he could be doing back-end update with a script that the SQL server agent runs or that he runs manually.

Comment: @Jim You think attacks only come from the public?  You don't think a script can be hacked?   I never trust external data even if it came from from my own code.

Comment: No, I think you're being silly and paranoid by telling someone not to use a great tool without knowing the situation in which they would be using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dynamic SQL for this:

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)

set @query = 'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@databaseNameTXT) + '(wStat_id) 
                values('+@wStat_id+')'

exec(@query)
```